# FirefoxDriver does not handle click properly

Tags: java, selenium, click, webdriver

has anyone solved this?

Whenever I have submit button, I have to go in workaround and send keys "Enter" to it. To be more specific:

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("my-test-site");
 WebElement confirmBid = driver.findElement(By.id("mainForm:aucPanelId:1:finishEditBid"));
 confirmBid.click();
```

does not work, nothing happens, value is not confirmed. However, if I change the last to:

```
 Keys enter = Keys.ENTER;
 confirmBid.sendKeys(enter.toString());
```

Works fine and the form is submitted.

However, the **click();** command works fine on links.

Any idea why is that like this?

Comment: Please provide a link to a page where this issue is reproducible (and also the testcase which is not working as you expect).

Comment: I am sorry, but so far the page is only in our local intranet... So, are you supposing, that for you its working fine and I / my application is wrong?

Comment: I am guessing your usage of it might be incorrect. As you can imagine, it is not really possible to make any suggestions unless it is reproducible on our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some problems with that myself at times. Not sure why it happens but you can use...

```
confirmBid.sendKeys(Keys.enter);
```

to make it a little cleaner.